# How to dynamicaly override __init__ of an sqlalchemy base class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am wondering why this doesn't work ?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)

def new_init(self, name):
    self.name = name

setattr(Test, '__init__', new_init)

Test(name='my_name')
```

It gives the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I would be expecting the same as if I were doing this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Test(name='my_name')
```

Which does work as expected.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, It’s like in any other  class instantiation sometime I want to modify/clean/generate attributes in the __init__. As for the dynamic part, I am trying to write a database factory that would generate tables and relationship with more concise but more restrictive syntax than the standard SQLAlchemy ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified why the above error is happening, I do not however understand this behaviour, if I get around to reading more and understanding I will update this answer.

`Test.name` is an `InstrumentedAttribute`, which is a subclass of `QueryableAttribute`.

`QueryableAttribute`'s `__init__` contains the following:

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        ...  # skipping
        impl: Optional[AttributeImpl] = None,
        ...  # skipping
    ):
        
        ...  # skipping

        # this attribute is non-None after mappers are set up, however in the
        # interim class manager setup, there's a check for None to see if it
        # needs to be populated, so we assign None here leaving the attribute
        # in a temporarily not-type-correct state
        self.impl = impl  # type: ignore
       
        ... # skipping
```

So when you create the class first, I guess the `Test.name` is not fully instrumented, i.e. it is missing an `impl`, which stops your `new_init` from working.

The second case, I would imagine the `Base` has further methods to handle it.

It might be worth starting a [github discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions) if you want further information.

Comment: Thank you, that must be it. I struggle finding the documentation on how those Base classes are implemented in order to find out the exact reason. I have to say though, I really can’t imagine a mechanism implemented by SQLAlchemy that would have this effect. I must be lacking some python concept. It feels to me that right before the instantiation, the interpreter “state” should be the exact same in both exemple.